# Detect support for multiple background images?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I really want to make use of multiple background support (Webkit, Firefox 3.6+), but I would like to provide an alternative solution for browsers that don't support it. (IE, Firefox 3.5-).

Is there any way to detect support for this CSS feature? Or will I have to resort to browser sniffing?

**EDIT:** Javascript solutions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://www.modernizr.com/. This is a piece of javascript that will set up classes depending on what features the browser have. You can then use these classes in CSS.

Comment: Is in question any javascript mentioned?

Comment: @Miro - it wasn't mentioned, but it seems to be required. Modernizr does seem to answer the question.

Comment: @Miro: this is a solution which has not been ruled out by specification (yet), and which will work when correctly applied. Do you have any objections?

Comment: some people are surfing without scripts :)

Comment: @Miro: modernizr has a fallback feature, where it removes .no-js class from <html> when it exist. Then you can resolve having/not having JS in CSS.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a relatively old question but I thought I would add a JS snippet that can be used to sniff this. The code is taken from the Modernizr source but has been modified a bit:

```
function multipleBgTest(){

  var el_style = document.createElement("div").style;
  el_style.cssText = 'background:url(//:),url(//:),red url(//:)';

  // If the UA supports multiple backgrounds, there should be three occurrences
  // of the string "url(" in the return value for el_style.background
  return new RegExp("(url\\s*\\(.*?){3}").test(el_style.background);

}
```

If the function returns `true` then it is supported otherwise it will return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way in pure css to detect if multiple backgrounds are supported. But you can specify default background and then specify multiple backgrounds which resolves error with processing value and keeps old if it isn't supported.